# Apache RedirectMatch not matching double slash

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias, pcre

I want to redirect URLs with multiple consecutive slashes (e.g. `//`) in the path to have only one consecutive slash, e.g.
`https://example.com/a//b/c/` → `https://example.com/a/b/c/`.

My `.htaccess` file contains the following statement.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$ $1/$2
```

This doesn't work. However, the following variants do:

- just matching a single `/`,
- matching some other character, like `^(.*)q{2,}(.*)$`.

What's wrong with my `RedirectMatch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL-path that the `RedirectMatch` (mod_alias) directive matches against has probably already had multiple slashes reduced (a necessary step when the request is mapped to the filesystem).

To test for multiple slashes you need to use mod_rewrite and check against the `THE_REQUEST` server variable instead (in a preceding *condition*). `THE_REQUEST` is "unprocessed" and contains the first line of the request headers as sent from the client, eg. `GET /a//b/c/ HTTP/1.1`.

For example, try the following instead, near the top of the **root** `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This removes (via an external 301 redirect) multiple slashes anywhere in the URL-path part of the URL. (Although you should always test first with a 302 - temporary - redirect in order to avoid any potential caching issues.)

This uses the fact that the URL-path matched (and captured) by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* has already had multiple slashes resolved away. The `$1` backreference then uses this URL-path (less the multiple slashes) in the *substitution* string.

The regex `\s[^?]*//` in the *CondPattern* tests for multiple slashes in the URL-path and ensures we don't match multiple slashes in the query string (if any) - which would otherwise result in a redirect loop.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: I don't quite follow. Yes, Apache "resolves" it in that it serves `a/b//c/` just as it serves `a/b/c/` (I think this makes "resolves" a "rewrite"). But I want to redirect and don't understand how that's related.

Comment: @fionn I've added a bit more explanation (and improved wording). "Resolves" is not a "rewrite". There is no "rewrite" here, only a "redirect". You mention "rewrite" in your question, but it's really a "redirect". (It needs to be a "redirect" in order to fix any canonical URL issues that could otherwise affect SEO.)

Comment: @fionn Which bit don't you understand? Have you tried my solution above?

Comment: Oops! Have edited my question to remove the word "rewrite". My interpretation: `mod_rewrite` has already squashed the multiple slashes, so `mod_alias`, operating at a level higher, does not see them so fails to match as a result. Is that correct?

Comment: This doesn't work, it will redirect `/a//b/` to `/b/` instead of `/a/b/`.

Comment: @fionn It would only do that if the `.htaccess` file is located in the `/a/` subdirectory, not the root. The `.htaccess` file should be located in the root directory.